# Значение слова "окисли"

Tags: лексика

В произведении В. Одоевского "Игоша" встречается слово "окисли". Видимо, какое-то диалектное слово. А кто знает значение этого слова? Вот контекст.

*Мало мне было нянюшкиных слов, и я, бывало, как дверь ли, **окисли** отворится — тотчас забегу посмотреть: не тут ли безрукий — и, как он ни увертлив, верно бы мне попался, если бы в то время батюшка не возвратился из города и не привез с собою новых игрушек, которые заставили меня на время позабыть о безруком.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Там [окно ли](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nicVAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNt9i5qJLoAhUPO8AKHZsXAI8Q6wEIOTAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0&f=false).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка распознавания, такое часто встречается в электронных текстах.

Comment: Это не просто ["электронные тексты"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=V71rCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=znGH4yb8u9&sig=ACfU3U1IzbSPP2gOpOYtH_G6AS4htn9DiQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8pK28sJLoAhXql4sKHXTPBDkQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false). Теперь уже ошибки былых распознаваний закрепляются в твёрдых переизданиях.